# Upgrading Kohana from 3.0.7 to 3.0.8 error

Tags: frameworks, kohana, upgrade

I update my Kohana do 3.0.8 from 3.0.7 and i get this:
[image]

My function is:

```
public function unique_key_exists($value)
{
    return (bool) DB::select(array('COUNT("*")', 'total_count'))
                    ->from($this->_table_name)
                    ->where($this->unique_key($value), '=', $value)
                    ->execute($this->_db)
                    ->get('total_count');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine your function's signature as follows:

```
public function unique_key_exists($value, $field = NULL)
```

See, if in the parent class this function is defined with this signature, you have to follow it in the subclasses - or face the E_STRICT warning.